# JAVASCRIPT: Is that possible to avoid window to close with event beforeunload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

Is that possible to cancel a window close in javascript (via mootools or not) with something like below?

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload",function(){doSomething(); return false;})
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  You use *onbeforeunload* and return the string that you want prompted.  The browser handles all the work from there for obvious reasons.  If the user is okay to leave simply return nothing.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() 
{
   if(...) {
      return 'Your changes have NOT been saved.';
   }

   return;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank goodness no.

You can however give the user a confirm box just in case they have unsaved changes or some such thing.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'You have unsaved changes.'
};
```

Don't annoy your users by trying to keep them on your page. It's only going to backfire, and cause people to actively dislike your site.

Comment: you don't need to call `confirm()`. Just returning a string is just fine.

Comment: Also, `onunload` should be `unbeforeunload`

Comment: Well, good for you but in this case, calling `confirm` is infact wrong. All browsers expect a string to be returned: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload